# If $g$ is continuous then it is Borel measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be $\mathbb{R}^r$  for some $r \geq 1$, D be a subset of X and $g: D \to \mathbb{R}$.
I am trying to show If g is continuous then it is Borel measurable.

This is the proof I have.

Take $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $\gamma = \{G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^r$ is open , $g(x) < a$   $\forall x \in G \cap D \}$. Set $G_0 = \cup \gamma = \{ x: \exists G \in \gamma , x \in G \}$.

> How can we deduce from this that $G_0$ is a union of open sets?

We now look at the case when $g(x) < a$
then because g is continuous, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|g(y) - g(x)|< a-g(x)$ whenever $y \in D$ and $||y-x||< \delta$.

> Why is $|g(y) - g(x)|< a-g(x)$? Why $a-g(x)$?

We know $\{y : ||y-x|| < \delta\}$ is open so it belongs to $G_0$. If $x \in G_0 \cap D$ then there exists a $G \in \gamma$ such that $x\in G$ then $g(y) < a$ for every $y \in G \cap D$.

> How do we know that if $x \in G_0 \cap D$ then there exists a $G \in \gamma$ such that $x\in G$ then  $g(y) < a$ for every $y \in G \cap D$ ?
>   What does this mean?

$G_0$ is open is it is a Borel set. As $a$ is arbitrary, $g$ is measurable.

> Why is $a$ being arbitrary significant?

Comment: What is $D$ in the definition of $\gamma$?

Comment: My mistake, I left out the initial definitions.

Comment: if $g\;$ is continous then for every open set $A  \subset \mathbb R \; f^{-1}(A)\;$  is open. Hence f is measurable

Comment: @xpenguen does that help with understanding the proof?

Comment: Doesnt help with your proof but that should help you to proof it much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following method is cleaner: Let $g$ be continuous, and let $\mathcal{B} = \{U \ |\ g^{-1}(U)\text{ is Borel}\}$. Prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Certainly it must contain all open sets, since $g$ is continuous, and hence it will also contain all Borel-sets.

**EDIT**: I don't really understand the proof in your original post. It looks like the idea is to take an arbitrary real number $a$, and to consider the preimage $g^{-1}(-\infty,a) = \{x\in D\ |\ g(x) < a\}$ in some sense, and prove that it is open, and hence Borel. But I would have thought it was well-known at this point that the pre-image of an open set under a continuous function is open.

I understand some of the steps of the proof, but I don't get the big picture. If you have the possibility of taking a photo of your book and pasting it into your original post, maybe I can have another look.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I would love to understand the proof I have in my question, would you be able to help me understand that proof please?

Comment: @Aljabra ok, if you are still interested, I'll have a look at it later.

Comment: yes I am interested. Thank you

Comment: @Aljabra I tried reading the proof, but it doesn't make much sense to me. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The Boreal algebra is generated by the open sets in $\mathbb R$. Hence its enough to show that for every open set $\; A\; $ in $\mathbb R \; f^{-1}(A) \;$ is open in $\,D\,$ which will be true for every continious function.

Comment: How do you show this?

Comment: You mean the part, that it´s enough to show that $\, f^{-1}(A) \,$ is open ?

Comment: yeah. out of interest is Fremlin's measure theory not a good book to learn from? Every proof I show other people out of that book gets slated, not on this forum but elsewhere.